# Access XHR object in callback of trackPageView() using Piwik.js (matomo)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, matomo, piwiktracker

I am using [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) for tracking page view. I have a requirement where on completion of XHR request of track page view I need to perform some operation which involves accessing `xhr` (`XmlHttpRequest`) object. I figured out that with `trackPageView()` described [here](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript) we can pass  `customTitle, customData, callback`. I was able to pass a callback function as a parameter but I am not able to access `xhr` in the callback.
Is there some way I can access `xhr` in the callback function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is now solved thanks to a recent pull request:

https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/pull/13665